# InstallShield what to give to client

Tags: installshield

I used InstallShield to create an installer for my project.

It included the following files (deeply nested in a file directory):

program files (folder),0x0409.ini, setup.exe, Setup.ini, applicationName.msi

Am I supposed to provide all these to the client and have him click the setup.exe button? or is there a nicer (easier) way to make it clear what the client needs to click?

I know you can just have the applicationName.msi, but why did they create a setup.exe program then?

Answer (score 0):

Installshield creates a setup.exe if you have your project's Release configured to create one. Choose "no" under Releases | Setup.exe tab | Setup Launcher. Those other files you mention should not be needed by the client.

Comment: Note that if the installation uses prerequisites, multiple languages, or multiple instances, you typically cannot (or cannot safely) disable the creation of setup.exe. In that case, to simplify things, the other files can typically all be compressed inside setup.exe so that a single file can be provided.